# What does よ bring in 「〜ないでよね」？

Tags: nuances, particles, て-form, imperatives, particle-ね

I sometimes hear or read sentences such as:

1. 行かないでよね！
2. 聞かないでよね！

I get 「行かないでね！」and 「行かないでよ！」 but I wonder what nuance is added when both of them are used like in these examples.

I have the feeling that these are often used by young girls but I am not sure. Can it be used by men too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's basically the same as (imperative +)  よ, i.e. request <s>when the listener doesn't seem to share the same recognition as the speaker</s> when you doubt that the opponent does it.

In falling tone<sup>*1</sup>, it stands for complaint as well as よ, and extra ね softens it, sort of.

<sup>(*1 **Edit**: I wrote "falling tone" because of similarity to falling よ, but I should have written it as "lower intonation" or so. This ね pronounced lower than that of the below, but it can be still higher than the preceding よ per se. So, it's actually not "falling".)</sup>

In rising tone<sup>*2</sup>, it sounds more imploring than simple (imperative +) よ？, which prompts attention to not forget about it.

<sup>(*2 This "rising tone" means that ね is pronounced higher than よ. If you further pronounce ね itself in sharp falling tone, it functions as (imperative +) よ with interjection ね, and the result is roughly the same.)</sup>

And, now that you mention it, it could sound a little too wimpy for men to use, though I think it depends on people, after all.